# how to set passwords to mkusb?

Tags: linux, usb

[Live USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_USB) pendrives are used for the purposes of secure transactions e.g. banking, payments, secure e-mail, SSH connection, etc.

So for a typical secure use, it is important to create USB with password, not change password after install.

The most reliable *Live USB system* maker of Linux (Debian and Ubuntu) is `mkusb`... But  `man mkusb | grep -i password` is empty, say nothing about *"ask me the passwords before!"*  (root and user passwords).

---

Summary: How to set the passwords before  finished the installation? there are a workaround for it?

Need the source-code of a program (or shell commands) that solves the problem.

### Illustrating

Suppose an installation process like [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) (so using a sys image like [debianLive8-gnome](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/debian-live-8.7.1-amd64-gnome-desktop.iso)).

The pendrive *states* in a **secure process installation**:

1. blank pendrive
2. secure system installed
3. secure passwords enabled
4. running secure pendrive

[image: safe]

The pendrive states in **unsafe process**:

[image: unsafe process]

Here we add an unsafe state,

5. running (**unsafe!**) pendrive

Which, also, may compromise the following state (3).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean a password inside the operation system which launches from the USB pendrive, but not a password to the bootable stick itself. In this case, normally, user credentials are flashed into the bootable image. The way how it works and is configured - depends on the distro of the live OS you're gonna use. And you can refer to the distro documentation to get them known. Also, these credentials are not unique and will be same at every OS instance started from that ISO. If you need to have unique credentials, then you need do some configuration changes to the ISO to "flash" your new passwd over to there. This is not a trivial process and if you like to follow it, you will need to learn how leave CDs work in general, have knowlege how your particular OS is configured (in most general case you need `man passwd` and relevant topics). Hopefully that helps.

UPDATE: keep in mind, any who can physically get (read) your bootable image will be able to do the same manipulations as you did :). That means, the security of this approach is quite weak.

Comment: Thanks @dmi!  Yes password inside USB pendrive, and "before finished the installation".    Can you show an example (commands sequence) for Debian?   Suppose [debian-live-8.7.1-amd64-gnome-desktop.iso](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/debian-live-8.7.1-amd64-gnome-desktop.iso).

Comment: Hi, about your "update", you say that [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) strategy is not secure?  Tails use a Live USB with a bootable image derived from *debian-live-8.7-gnome*.

Comment: Telling about the security I meant, that everyone who can boot from your image has a full access to all your data (including credentials) flashed to the image. Thus, any authorization, using these credentials won't be secure anymore. Besides that, please keep in mind other security measures like passwords expiration and so on which won't be available with this approach - for everything you will have to modify the boot image.

Comment: Hi, I edited, see the new "Illustration" section. I need the  passwords in the installing process, before to run the system.

Comment: Does `chroot` to the new root and `passwd` from there do what you need?

Comment: You need to boot (run the system) the pendrive to run commands... So need to put into unsafe mode, see "state 5" illustration.  Of course, is also unsafe to use `chroot` and `passwd` (state 3) *into unsafe state*.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood the meaning of "unsafe state". My recommendation is relevant to the moment of time when you have your pendrive image unpacked or mounted rw. At that time you can using the commands I wrote to change the passwd within the ISO if it is configured in a standard way. Then write the ISO to the USB and boot.